# How to check if two or more keys are mapped to same value?

Tags: java

This is my first time posting on here, although I've been visiting quite a few times. I apologize if this post is incorrectly formatted.

I'm almost through writing a method that accepts a Map of Strings to Strings that returns true if no two keys map to the same value, or if the map is empty.

For instance:
Customer 1=888-123-4567, Customer 2=888-234-5678, Customer 3=888-345-6789 is TRUE.

Customer 1=888-888-8888, Customer 2=888=234=5678, Customer 3=888-888-8888 is FALSE, because of Customer 1 and Customer 3 are mapped to the same phone number.

Here is my code so far:

```
    public boolean isUnique ( Map<String, String> m ) {
        Map<String, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        if ( !m.isEmpty() ) {
            for ( String key : m.values() ) {
                m2.put(key, 1);
                if ( m2.containsKey(key) )
                    m2.put(key, m2.get(key) + 1);
            }

            for ( Integer v : m2.values() ) {
                if( v > 1 )
                    return false;
            }
       }
       else
           return true;
    }
```

I'm getting a false even though are no keys that are mapped more than once to a value. Can someone explain what is wrong with my conditions or any other problems they notice? Thank you!

Comment: what are the keys? is it "Customer 1=888-888-8888"? not just numbers?

Comment: Since you're returning `boolean` you could prevent some unnecessary processing if you `return false` as soon as you detect a duplicate instead of keeping a tally. Or you could convert it to set logic `return new HashSet<String>(m.values()).size() == m.values().size();`

Comment: Origineil I had it set up that way originally, and I'll revert back to that. Thank you for letting me know that my intuition made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice job on your formatting and thank you for putting time into your post. It is greatly appreciated. Your problem lies with you putting the value (key) in before you check if it contains

```
for ( String key : m.values() ) {
    // you put your key in
    m2.put(key, 1);
    // check if it contains the key.... 
    // Of course it does because you just put it in there
    if ( m2.containsKey(key) ) {
        // increment it again
        m2.put(key, m2.get(key) + 1);
    }
}
// after this loop is complete every value in the m2 map is >= 2
```

Comment: ug_, I thought I what I wrote would increment the value attached the key. Is there a better way of phrasing it?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what you were saying. I created an if-else block in that for-each loop and it worked out fine. Thanks for your help, ug_ and everyone else.